# swagger.json not generated for controller that inherits from a base class

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.1

In my net core api application all the controllers inherit from a base controller.

Because of this, swagger doesn't work.

I create a sample project with visual studio and swagger works fine

But when I create a base class (Test.cs) that inherits from ControllerBase and I change ValuesController.cs to inherit from Test instead of ControllerBase, swagger don't work.

I got the error

*Failed to load API definition.
Fetch errorundefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json*

Thank you for your help!

Here is my code:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Test", Version = "v1" });
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.XML";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger.json", "Test");        
    });
}
```

**Test.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class Test : ControllerBase
    {
        public void MyTest()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**ValuesController.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    // This works
    // public class ValuesController : ControllerBase

    // This doesn't works
    public class ValuesController : Test
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Test
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After posting my question I found this:
[link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/730)
but I dont' have 2 methods with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better to use [NoAction] to tell the Swagger Generator this is not an action, no required to generate. Example, below.

```cs
 [NonAction]
 public OkObjectResult Ok(string message){}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem changing my base class Test.cs

```
public void MyTest()
```

to

```
protected void MyTest()
```

Comment: After creating an inherited Controller, I was surprised with the error `undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json`. You saved me a lot of time! Thanks! (Using `.net core` v3.1 and `NSwag.AspnetCore` v13.6.2.)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid this issue and exclude controller public method from Swagger API you could use following attribute:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public void MyTest()
{
}
```